# How does @parallel=false work when put at the top of a scenario and not feature

Tags: dsl, karate

If we put @parallel=false only at the top of a scenario and not on a feature , then will it stop running the test cases in parallel and still run the features in parellel?

My whole intention is to not run scenarios parallely but run the features parallely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Features will always run in parallel if you use the [parallel runner](https://github.com/intuit/karate#parallel-execution).

If you add the `@parallel=false` annotation - it will only affect the individual `Scenario`.

Comment: Cool Thanks Peter!!

Comment: To confirm, does mean `@parallel=false` above the Scenario is only useful if it's a Scenario Outline?

Comment: @anutter no. it applies to any kind of `Scenario` even those coming out of an "outline". but note that other scenarios can run in parallel. this tag only ensures that a scenario with this tag will not run at the same time as another scenario with this same tag